# Branch Points of the function $z^{(1 + i)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

I don't seem to understand what branch points and branch cuts are. Can anyone tell me the concepts by finding the branch points and the branch cuts of the following funcition. $$z^{(1 + i)}$$

Comment: I would start with simpler functions, if you're trying to get the hang of branches (branch points/cuts) of analytic functions. Do you know about branches of $\sqrt z$? of $\log z$?

Comment: Yes, for these function, the modulus of the function doesn't depend on the argument of $z$. But in case of $z^{(i + 1)}$, it does. This is what is confusing me. Intuitively I think z = 0 is a branch point. But I am not able to prove it.

Comment: $|\log z|$ definitely does depend upon the argument of $z$, even if you've already fixed a branch. What is $|\log 1|$? What is $|\log i|$?

Comment: Oh! That clears the confusion I guess. So for $log z$ there is a change in magnitude on the change in argument. Thus one rotation in the $z$ plane containing the origin results in a different mapping to the $w$ plane, hence making in multiple valued ($f(z)$ maps $z$ to $w$). Thank you :D.

Comment: Indeed, that is a second reason that the magnitude changes. One fact about $\log z$ worth remembering is that the real part of $\log z$ is just $\log |z|$ (this is the usual logarithm of a real number), whlie the imaginary part of $\log z$ is the argument of $z$ (which, as you point out, is multivalued). In particular, the real part of $\log z$ doesn't depend on the argument of $z$ (nor the branch you choose), but the imaginary part and hence the magnitude definitely do (as well as on the branch you choose).

Answer (score 1):

Take any $z,a\in\Bbb{C}.$ Then usually $z^a$ is defined as $e^{a\log z},$ where $\log z=\ln |z|+\arg z$ is [the complex logarithm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH24qluKzRAhVP1GMKHQigCt4QFggkMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FComplex_logarithm&usg=AFQjCNFaDjsIchyUNqfaCtVcz-5PlUV2MA) of $z.$ Therefore $$z^{1+i}=e^{(1+i)\ln|z|+(-1+i)\arg(z)}.$$ Obviously, once we travel along a closed path enclosing the origin in
the counterclockwise direction $$\arg(z)\to 2\pi+\arg(z).$$
Hence $z=0$ is a branch point of $z^{1+i}.$
Also changing the variable $z\to\dfrac1z,$ we can see that there is another branch point at $z=\infty.$
These are the only branch points of this function.

Comment: $z^a=\exp(z\log a)$?  How strange, I always thought it was  $z^a=\exp(a\log z)$.  I'd check that.

Comment: Oh. It is my mistake. Thank you for pointing out it.